# A tag HTML tem um atributo ou valor de atributo não permitido

Tags: html

A tag HTML tem um atributo ou valor de atributo não permitido.
O problema persiste nesse trecho do código:

```
<form class="wpcf7-form" action="/wp-admin/post.php?post=4648&amp;
action=edit&amp;message=1#wpcf7-f2766-o1" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
```

Answer (score 2):

Tem uma "quebra de linha" na sua url da `action=""`!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja o que fala no validador **W3C**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se vc corrigir esse url vc vai ver que não vai apresentar Erro na validação, pelo menos no validador da **W3C** não da erro! https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Tenha cuidado para colocar tudo concatenado, sem deixar quebrar a linha**

```
<form class="wpcf7-form" action="/wp-admin/post.php?post=4648&amp;action=edit&amp;message=1#wpcf7-f2766-o1" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
</form>
```